# Custom "list of" command for lab notebook

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I'm keeping my lab notebook for my PhD in LaTeX. I have it set up such that each "project" has its own chapter.

When I make a new entry into the notebook I use a custom "entry command":

```
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \marginnote{#1}%
}
```

where the first field is the date and the second is a brief explanation of what the entry is about, e.g.

```
\entry{2015-04-08}{Information on geospatial data}
```

Is there a way to make a "list of" feature for the "entry" command that is separated by chapter such that I can get a quick overview of what and when I did a certain task/experiment without having to dive into the document? This would include field `#1` and `#2`.

Or is there a better way to set this up? I would prefer use a command if possible, and not have to switch to an environment.

Comment: May be you can use `todonotes`...

Comment: Could you give some feedback, please? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

I used the standard `book` class, modified the 'appearance (but not the logic of `\entry` and the `tocloft` package to make automatic entries to a `.lab` file, containing the date and the note.

This is typeset using various `\cft.....` commands provided by `tocloft`.

Additionally, there is an empty separating line after each chapter in the `\listoflabentries` output.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}



\newcommand{\listoflabentriesname}{List of Entries}
\newlistof[chapter]{labentries}{lab}{\listoflabentriesname}
\setlength{\cftlabentriesnumwidth}{3cm}

%%% no dots
\renewcommand{\cftlabentriesdotsep}{\cftnodots}

%% Stolen for tocloft documentation
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{0.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftlabentriespresnum}{\hfill} % note the double `l'
\renewcommand{\cftlabentriesaftersnum}{\hspace*{\mylen}}
\addtolength{\cftlabentriesnumwidth}{\mylen}

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{labentries}
  \marginnote{#1}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \renewcommand{\thelabentries}{\bfseries #1} 
  % Adding the entry to the \jobname.lab file
  \addcontentsline{lab}{labentries}{\protect\numberline{\thelabentries}\bfseries#2}
}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{%
  \addtocontents{lab}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoflabentries

\chapter{First}
\entry{2015-04-08}{Information on geospatial data}

\chapter{Second}
\entry{Stardate 5934}{Captain's log: Data becomes sillier every day}
\entry{Stardate 5934.6}{Captain's log: Date with Dr. Beverly Crusher quite disappointing. Don't know what to do now}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a quick hack (out of nothing), more improvement later on (perhaps)

Comment: Thanks! This nearly works for me, I'm getting some errors which seem to be causing there to be no separation for each chapter.

Ideally I'd like to get the `\listoflabentries` at the beginning of each chapter, so that they are more explicit to each part of the notebook.

This is a good start though, and I should be able to get a better idea of where to head from here.

Comment: @chasely: If there would have an example to work with my idea would have been better too ;-)

Comment: Had a little bit of time to look at this today. Is there a way to combine this with the `minitoc` package?

Comment: @chasely: Possibly, but `minitoc` is unmaintained for years. I like it too, but as written, unmaintained and endangered to become outdated. `jfbu`, a user here, wrote `etoc`, with similar features